# HTML 3 columns header

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to make fixed header that is splited in 3 parts on horizontal. The central part have 1000px width, other 2 parts have equal sizes with auto width. Also the left part have an image with an edge glued to the central part. I have tried a couple of solutions, however i accomplished this only by using tables. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: [Show us](http://jsfiddle.net) what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 1):

You can make that using divs, displayed as table-cell.

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="l">l</div>
    <div class="m">m</div>
    <div class="r">r</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.header > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
.l {
    background: lightblue;
}
.m {
    background: lightgreen;
    width: 500px;
}
.r {
    background: lightblue;
}
```

Also check [**the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h3nDh/).

Answer (score 1):

I would restrict the use of tables to tabular data. Based on your description, I think this will work for you. What you are doing is setting a fixed width to your middle column and setting the width of the end columns to 50% and then setting a negative margin on each to half of the width of the center column. The CSS could be a little more efficient.

http://jsfiddle.net/CLRxq/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">Add Image here</div>
    <div class="center">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="right">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.center {
    float: left;
    width: 1000px;
    background: red;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    background: green;
    margin-right: -500px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
    margin-left: -500px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with tables or divs, it's up do you, though, for flexibility and consistency I recommend doing it on divs.

**Table:**

```
<table width="1200" height="100">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td width="1000"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Div:**

Go here, the center div is the big one, side div are the others, don't remove the clear div, it is only a float fix for the html. Just change the CSS accordingly to what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/EsQak/